# How to Pass values in web services

Tags: php, web-services, get

I have created a sample web services, This will return me a Json Data. looks like below.

> http://127.0.0.1/Webservices/Oraconnect.php

```
     <?php
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        $something = array();
        array_push($something, array('say' => 'omg', 'dsay' => 'D omg'));
        array_push($something, array('say' => 'bla', 'dsay' => 'D bla'));

        $cont = array('result'=>$something);

        $jsonresult = json_encode($cont);

        print_r($jsonresult);



?>
```

Result:

```
{
    result: [
        {
            say: "omg",
            dsay: "D omg",
        },{
            say: "bla",
            dsay: "D bla",
        },
    ]
}
```

Now I want validated with UserName, which should take Value and change response accordingly.

something like this.

http://127.0.0.1/Webservices/Oraconnect.php?user=john

How can I add this validation and Change the response accordingly. Appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like that

```
<?php
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        if($_GET["user"])
        {
             $user = $_GET["user"];
             // write your code that will use the user name
        }
        else
        {
            // return error or anything said the user is missing
        }

?>
```